# Notification hub: Installation templates not created again once deleted registrations

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Endpoint - PUT https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/installations/{id}

Once the user registers with Device A, We create push notification templates with the above endpoint(`Working properly and registering templates`):
Request body:

```
{
    "installationId": "85c00d7d-1fcb-94ad-a394-59b42b24428d",
    "pushChannel": "ckdcS-wPD6Wiv7r2HJls2J4Zr4ocj-nXLHP1iJGNWx7w-FsFkgK7ZpdMEm8k4Eo",
    "platform": "gcm",
    "templates": {
        "mesaageTemplate": {
            "body": "{\"data\":{\"notId\":\"#(notId)\",\"title\":\"$(title)\",\"body\":\"$(body)\",\"badge\":\"#(badge)\",\"pageName\":\"$(pageName)\",\"pageParams\":\"$(pageParams)\",\"image\":\"twitter\",\"image-type\":\"circle\",\"style\":\"inbox\"}}",
            "tags": [
                "User_123456"
            ]
        }
    },
    "secondaryTiles": {}
}
```

Again user registers with Device B, we delete the existing templates of that user(Device A) and register new templates for Device B **-Working properly.**

Again, the User login with Device A, the endpoint is not creating the template registrations in the notification hub. (It is sending the same installation id when user logged in with Device A the first time) - **Not Registering**

can you suggest a way to resolve this?

Comment: Howdy - I'm afraid I don't quite understand the scenario. Is the installationId changing each time the user logs in with a new device?

Comment: @MarStr yes, if we login with new device. But, in this scenario I am registering with device A then B and again A.

Comment: These should be independent - each device having its own Installation ID and pushChannel. So there shouldn't be any interference between the two, they could both live side by side or without the other. What happens if you just skip the second device altogether, just logging out and back in?

Comment: @MarStr Yes, Each device has its own Installation Id. but, I am not uninstalling the app when I login into another device. so, It does not change the Installation Id. When the user login in into another device we send the push to the old device and log out the user. we manage one login on one device only.